# React-Native Android ScrollView can't get event from onScroll

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, gesture

If there is only one item or few items in ScrollView on Android, I won't get any event from `onScorll`. In iOS, I still could get the event because the `bounces`.

My problem is how could I listen to the scroll offset on Android with a list? I've tried `PanResponder`, but in my case, I would like to detect the swipe down and up gesture in a vertical `Flatlist`.

Answer (score 1):

`Flatlist` is built internally using the `responder` API, so if it doesn't do exactly what you want then you definitely can use `PanResponder`.

If there is only a few items in your data array then the list can't scroll, so no scroll will be triggered.

If you are just trying to track a swipe gesture for example do dismiss something, that isn't really what `Flatlist` was designed to solve, and you could use `PanResponder` directly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I understand you well, what you meant is to implement a scrollview using PanResponder?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved this problem by adding `PanResponder` for `FlatList`. When there are just few items, `PanResponder` works fine. On the other hand, if there are many items, I can get the `nativeEvent` from `onScroll`.